# Creating a background service for a finished app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service, background

I am fairly new to android development, and I want to customize an open source browser application to suite my usecase.

So what is my usecase:

I use an Oculus Quest 2 running Android. As with any Android device, you can sideload any app on it, but unfortunately the OS is very rigorous with killing background tasks, making it impossible to have Discord or Spotify running in the background while playing a game, which was my plan.

So I thought about it and came up with the idea of creating my own browser that implements the functionality to prevent it from being killed by the OS itself, and then in the browser I can open the web application of Spotify or Discord or any other web service to listen to it.

I have now decided to use the [FOSS browser](https://github.com/scoute-dich/browser) which I found on github and wanted to modify it to keep it open in the background. Unfortunately, I know next to nothing about Android app development and I don't even know if it's even possible to add this kind of functionality to an existing app without completely rewriting it. I hope my explanation is clear and that there is someone who can help me with this task.

Some keywords I already found out about are:

- creating a service (background service)
- foregrounding -> to tell the system that the app is important to the user and shall only be closed if memory is very limited

There is already one app out there which is able to run in the background of the oculus quest, so there is definitly a way of perfoming this task but unfortunatly I dont know how... yet

Comment: Hi were you able to make any progress on this? I have limited exp with android as well and am also looking into ways for sideloading background apps on quest